# Question from Mac Lane and Birkoff (Chapter II, section 2, problem 11)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I pretty sure that I know how to solve the following problem, but I have a few quick questions about it. First the problem:

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group and let $X$ be a set with a binary operation $\square$. Further, assume that there is an epimorphism $\phi : (G, \cdot) \rightarrow (X, \square)$ of binary operations. Show that $(X, \square)$ is also a group under $\square$.

In order to turn $X$ into a group, I'm pretty sure that one should define the operation as: $x_1 \square x_2 := \phi(g_1 \cdot g_2)$, where $\phi(g_i) = x_i$.

EDIT: as pointed out below, the binary operation $\square$ is already defined, but because we have a morphism of operations it is true that $\phi(g_1 \cdot g_2) = \phi(g_1) \square \phi(g_2)$.

My first question is do we need 'epi' so that each $x\in X$ has a preimage in $G$, thus allowing us to define the operation in $X$ in terms of the operation in $G$?

Next, I was originally worried about the situation where we have two different elements of $G$ mapping to the same element in $X$. As this could possibly lead to $\square$ giving multiple outputs for the same operation: that is, if $\phi(g_1) = \phi(g_1') = x_1$ with $g_1 \neq g_1'$, does it follow that $\phi(g_1 \cdot g_2) = \phi(g_1' \cdot g_2)$ even though $g_1 \cdot g_2 \neq g_1' \cdot g_2$? I'm pretty sure the answer to this is yes as: if $g_3 = g_1 \cdot g_2$ and $g_3' = g_1 \cdot g_2$, then $\phi(g_3) = \phi(g_1 \cdot g_2) = \phi(g_1) \square \phi(g_2) = \phi(g_1') \square \phi(g_2) = \phi(g_1' \cdot g_2) = \phi(g_3')$. But, I feel a little uncomfortable about this explanation (i.e., is it valid?).

With this definition, I think that I've shown $(X,\square)$ satisfies the properties of a group. Am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The operation $\square$ on $X$ is already defined, so you cannot define it yourself. But in fact we have been told that $\phi(g_1 \cdot g_2) = \phi(g_1) \square \phi(g_2)$, because we were told that $\phi$ is a morphism. So that information is given. And the answer to your first question is clearly yes, we need $\phi$ to be surjective for the proof to work.

Comment: Regarding the "is epimorphism needed" question: Multiplication modulo $3$ is not a group (it has a zero element), but the non-zero elements form a group, which is cyclic of order two.

Comment: @DerekHolt , Oh, you are right. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @user1729, ah, thanks!